# MySql select table dynamically

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to select all data form one of those tables based on the condition ?

```
SELECT * FROM  
CASE WHEN (another query which will return integer)>0 THEN products ELSE sub_products END
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design, but generally you'd just LEFT JOIN both tables, and see which one sticks. And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: products and sub_products contain valid table names?

Comment: Yes they are valid table names and please ignore the LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Modify IntResultQuery below to contain your query which returns a scalar value.

Modify a.Rslt to be the name of the column with the scalar value.

```
SELECT *
FROM (IntResultQuery) A
LEFT JOIN Products
 on 1=1 and A.Rslt>0
LEFT JOIN Sub_products
 on 1=1 and A.Rslt<=0
```

Though I agree this design is strange; and you'll get column names from both tables so maybe not what you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM (IntResultQuery) A
LEFT JOIN Products
 on A.Rslt > 0
LEFT JOIN Sub_products
 on A.Rslt <= 0
```

This union approach assumes both tables have the same table structure.  By unioning the tables and creating a column which tells us the source of the data, we can take the scalar result from your query and pick the right rows from the unioned tables.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 0 as src, P.*
      FROM Products P
      UNION ALL
      SELECT -1 as src, SP.* 
      FROM Sub_products SP) Z
CROSS JOIN (IntResultQuery) A
WHERE Z.src > A.Rslt
```

This approach avoids the multiple columns for the two tables; but suffers if the tables structures are not identical.  You could specify the specific columns from each table desired assuming at least some match; and left join in the columns that don't match.  But this type of design gets challenging to maintain the data as it complicates which table needs to be updated when a change is needed.

Comment: `1 = 1`? that is alway true you can just remove that from the query.

Comment: True.  it's just a habit I have when I know that I'm not joining on PK/FK relationships between the tables.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Let me explain you the situation to make it more clear.

I have two tables 1. products and 2. sub_products. Each sub_products table item must have a products table item as parent ie. burger product may have child chicken burger, beef burger etc. On the other hand a parent product may not have any child like pepsi.

So what I need is if I don't have anything from sub_products table for a certain id then the product is in the products table.